# Why is this unusual Objective-C design pattern a bad idea?

Tags: objective-c

I've recently joined a new project with a large existing codebase which makes frequent use of a pattern I've never come across before either in practice or in any of the literature.

As an example:

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
@interface ClassA ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelOne;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTwo;
@end

@implementation ClassA
//...
@end
```

ClassAHelper.h

```
@interface ClassAHelper : NSObject
- (void)configureClassA:(ClassA *)classA;
@end
```

ClassAHelper.m

```
// here's the 'interesting' bit
@interface ClassA ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) UILabel *labelTwo;
@end

@implementation ClassAHelper

- (void)configureClassA:(ClassA *)classA {
    classA.labelTwo.text = @"wtf?";
}

@end
```

So basically, classes are declared with no (or very little) external interface, and access to those class's properties is achieved by declaring those properties the accessing class is interested in an anonymous category inside the implementation file of the accessing class.

I know that there are no such things as truly private instance properties in Objective-C, all ivars being equal before the runtime. I know that from the compiler's point of view there isn't any difference between having the anonymous category in-line in the other class's .m and #including it from a public .h. And I see how, because this second class extension isn't visible to that class's .m the compiler doesn't try to synthesise a second set of properties. However, this approach still makes me feel uneasy. Unfortunately, the only practical complaint I can come up with is that using this approach means having to keep two sets of property declarations in sync.

So over to you: Can you suggest a valid technical reason why this approach should be taken out behind the barn and shot? Or alternatively, tell me why I've got nothing to worry about (although I'd like something a little more substantial than "Well, it works, doesn't it?").

Comment: duplicated code is always bad (unless it is auto generated)

Comment: Yeah duplicated property declaration can only be bad.

Comment: However, this approach still makes me feel uneasy. Unfortunately, the only practical complaint I can come up with is that using this approach means having to keep two sets of property declarations in sync - Would seem a perfectly valid and strong argument against this practice.

Comment: Usually I have a public interface with no or readonly properties then I have a class continuation where everything is declared fully (all the properties readwrite). If I need to share a property with another class, I have a special `+Package` category where I duplicate the properties from the class continuation. Not a really good solution but readable and it works.

Comment: Like said, if you change a thing on labelTwo (for instance if you have to subclass UILabel), you'll have to do it twice. And if you use this pattern all over your project, you'll have to write 2 times more properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many pointed in comments, and as you said **code duplication** is generally a bad practice.

This code duplication is required for this particular pattern to access "private" (unexposed) properties from an external class.

That just does not make sense, in that case, the property should just be public, since it is used externaly from its class.

If you really need to hide *"internaly public but externaly private things"*, which only really makes sense like when for instance you are publishing an SDK to clients, a more classical approach, that does not bring this code redundancy, is to expose such members in a `Whatever+Private.h` header that you do not ship with your package.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly simple change to this pattern, which maintains the positives of hiding private properties, while alleviating the issue of code duplication, is to put those property declarations into a common header file:

ClassA-Private.h:

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassA ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelOne;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTwo;
@end
```

Which can be `#import`ed into both `ClassA.m` and `ClassAHelper.m`.